# Add stream operators to Qt object

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to add stream operators to an existing Qt object? I tried doing this in this example code (for `QFileSystemWatcher`), the last line don't compile. The `LineUser` example is compiled.

[Documentation for registering stream operators](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType-1).

```
#include <QtCore>

class LineUser {
public:
    int uId;
    QString passwd;
    qint8 statusType;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(LineUser)
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const LineUser &myObj) {
    out<<myObj.uId<<myObj.passwd<<myObj.statusType;
    return out;
}
QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &in, LineUser &myObj) {
    in>>myObj.uId>>myObj.passwd>>myObj.statusType;
    return in;
}

QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const QFileSystemWatcher &myObj) {
    return out;
}
QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &in, QFileSystemWatcher &myObj) {
    return in;
}

int main() {
    qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<LineUser>("LineUser");
    qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<QFileSystemWatcher>("QFileSystemWatcher");
}
```

The compiler message is long, here are some errors:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘QFileSystemWatcher::QFileSystemWatcher(const QFileSystemWatcher&)’
                 return new (where) T(*static_cast<const T*>(t));
note: ‘QFileSystemWatcher::QFileSystemWatcher(const QFileSystemWatcher&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
  class Q_CORE_EXPORT QFileSystemWatcher : public QObject error: ‘QObject::QObject(const QObject&)’ is private
         Q_DISABLE_COPY(QObject) 
error: within this context  class Q_CORE_EXPORT QFileSystemWatcher : public QObject note: declared here
         Q_DISABLE_COPY(QObject)
```

Comment: Consider trying to add a stream operator for `QFileSystemWatcher*` instead.

Comment: What does the signature look like for that, QFileSystemWatcher &*myObj?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType):

> Any class or struct that has a public default constructor, a public
>   copy constructor and a public destructor can be registered.

And from [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator):

> QObject has neither a copy constructor nor an assignment operator.
>   This is by design.

So apparently, there is a design limitation that prevents `QObject` derived to be registered as meta types (and it makes sense too because it is not necessary as meta information is generated for them by default), thus `qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators` is a no-go too.

It should work for `QFileSystemWatcher *` though.